# Power BI e SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, powerbi

Eu preciso passar um orçamento de integração para um servidor SQL Server, porém o trabalho tem uma condição, a conexão com o site do Power BI, em todo lugar que li não deixa claro se é possível ou não a conexão do site do Power BI ao SQL Server do Cliente, que não quer usar o Power BI Desktop, nem usar o banco no Azure e tão pouco partir para o Analisys Services!!

É possivel o site do Power BI acessar o SQL Server em um servidor DMZ do meu cliente?

Comment: Não vamos esquecer que a nova versão do Report Services está aceitando relatórios em formato Power BI, mas há questões de licença envolvidas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resposta do próprio site do Power BI

**O Power BI está disponível localmente?**

Não, o Power BI não está disponível como um serviço de nuvem privado e interno. No entanto, com o Power BI e Power BI Desktop, você pode se conectar com segurança às suas próprias fontes de dados locais. Com o Gateway de Dados Local, é possível se conectar dinamicamente ao servidor local do SQL Server Analysis Services e a outras fontes de dados. Você também pode realizar a atualização agendada com um gateway centralizado. Se um gateway não estiver disponível, será possível atualizar os dados de fontes de dados locais usando o Power BI Gateway – Personal.

É possível também exibir relatórios móveis do SQL Server local com os aplicativos do iOS do Power BI

**Ou Seja Sim você tem acesso a fontes de dados locais.**

Comment: Se lhe ajudou marque como resposta

Answer (score 0):

Você deve instalar em uma máquina que tem acesso ao SQL Server (consiga acessar pela rede e tenha os drives corretamente instalados) um gateway de dados local, e configurar-lo com a conta de acesso ao Power BI, depois de subir o relatório (por exemplo), ir no servidor do Power BI, acessar o *Conjuntos de dados + fluxos de dados*, e configurar a *conexão de gateway* com as credenciais necessárias para acesso a base de dados.
A própria documentação online do Power BI pode lhe ser útil através deste link:
https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/data-integration/gateway/service-gateway-install